# Two couples of variables =2

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi i need help for a problem:

I have 8 variables

```
int var1
int var2
int var3
int var4
int var5
int var6
int var7
int var8
```

I need to launch a void if a two couples of this variables are =2 there what is the best solution for do it ?

```
if (var1 ==2 && var2 ==2) -- ecc..
```

Sorry for my english if is not correct but i'm italian.

Comment: *"launch a void"* - Do you mean "call a method"?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the variables with an array of eight elements, here's a possible solution (comments added as explanation):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class ArrayCheck {
    // The method you're looking for
    private static boolean checkArray(int[] array) {
        // Let's count how many variables are equal
        // equal to 2 and store in twoCount
        int twoCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 2) {
                // Increment the count
                ++twoCount;
            }
            
            if (twoCount > 4) {
                // Here, at least two couples of variables
                // are equal to 2
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        // Note: you can also simplify this
        // footer to `return twoCount == 4;`
        
        if (twoCount == 4) {
            // Here, exactly two couples of variables
            // (four of them) are equal to 2
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][] arrays = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
            {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
            {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
        };
        
        for (int[] array : arrays) {
            System.out.printf("%s: ", Arrays.toString(array));
            final boolean isCouple = checkArray(array);
            if (isCouple) {
                System.out.printf("exactly two couples are equal to 2\n");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("invalid array\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]: invalid array
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]: invalid array
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]: invalid array
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]: invalid array
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]: exactly two couples are equal to 2
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]: invalid array
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]: invalid array
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Streams you can implement solution to get count of variable having value = 2 then you can check the count as per your requirement and call void method as shown below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ArrayCheck {

     public static void main(String []args) {
        int var1 = 0;
        int var2 = 2;
        int var3 = 0;
        int var4 = 0;
        int var5 = 3;
        int var6 = 2;
        int var7 = 0;
        int var8 = 0;
        
        
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8);
        
        
        long count = list.stream().filter(var -> (var == 2)).collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::new)).getCount();
        
        System.out.println(count);
        /*
        Check count = 4
        if(count == 4)
        {
           //call your void method 
        }
        */
     }
}
```